# How to leave spaces for error symbols

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, vim8

I'm using vim 8 with YCM.

When YCM finds an error, a symbol will popup as below:

[image]

As you see, there is a symbol before line `26`.

The problem is that it will make the whole window move to right a little to get some spaces to show the symbol `>>`.

My question is if it is possible to avoid this move?

I need this because vim 8 runs based on a kind of async mechanism. So if I type fast, the error symbol will appear and disappear alternately and this gonna make the window sway.

Comment: Would  `set signcolumn=yes` (or set it to "no") help?

Comment: @BLayer  Yeah, it helps. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those symbols are displayed in what's called the *signcolumn*. Fortunately, there's some degree of control over it using the `'signcolumn'` setting. Available values will cause the column to be shown:

```
   "auto"       only when there is a sign to display
   "no"         never
   "yes"        always
   "number"     display signs in the 'number' column. If the number
                column is not present, then behaves like "auto".
```

The default is "auto" which results in the behavior you're seeing.

Try setting it to "yes" (`:set signcolumn=yes`) or, if you don't even care to see the symbols, "no". Both will stop transient symbols from making your text jump around.